# How to set kerning (spacing between characters) on UINavigationBar title - Swift or Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, user-interface, kerning

I've got my nav bar mostly customized to my liking, but I'm trying to increase the kerning using `NSKernAttributeName`. I'm using the appearance proxy to set the nav bar to white text and a custom font, but when I try to add kerning it doesn't take effect.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                     [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                     [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20.0], NSFontAttributeName,
                                                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0], NSKernAttributeName, nil]];
```

Do I need to do something else to add some of the less common attributes like kerning to the title label?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

According to the documentation, the `titleTextAttributes` of `UINavigationBar` only lets you specify the font, text color, text shadow color, and text shadow offset.

If you want to use other attributes, you can create a `UILabel` with the `NSAttributedString` you want, and set it as the `titleView` for your controller's `navigationItem`

For example:

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [UILabel new];
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor],
                             NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20.0],
                             NSKernAttributeName: @2};
titleLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.navigationItem.title attributes:attributes];
[titleLabel sizeToFit];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
```

Comment: I overrode `setTitle:` in a view controller subclass that I share so you don't have to do this everywhere.

Comment: One unfortunate side effect of using a `titleView` is it seems to mess up some accessibility behaviour.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990907/how-to-get-voice-over-to-read-out-title-when-new-view-controller-is-pushed/37165253#37165253

Answer (score 8):

I've tried many different ways to accomplish this and found that you can only change the font, text color, text shadow color, and text shadow offset of UINavigationBar as @Jesús A. Alvarez above have said.

I've converted the code in Swift and it works:

```
let titleLabel = UILabel()

let attributes: NSDictionary = [
    NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20),
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor(),
    NSKernAttributeName:CGFloat(2.0)
]

let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "UINavigationBar Title", attributes: attributes as? [String : AnyObject])

titleLabel.attributedText = attributedTitle
titleLabel.sizeToFit()
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
```

Answer (score 3):

Above answer updated for **Swift 4**

I created a superclass, where I defined this method, which you can call from each subclass you want:

```
func setNavigationTitle(_ title: String, kern: CGFloat) {
    let titleLabel = UILabel()

    let attributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18),
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
        NSAttributedStringKey.kern: kern] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]

    let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: attributes)

    titleLabel.attributedText = attributedTitle
    titleLabel.sizeToFit()
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
}
```

Comment: I'm curious how you handle very long titles. How do you prevent your `titleLabel` from covering the right & left navigationItem barButtons? I have been trimming the string after X characters but it's not very precise :(

Answer (score 0):

### UIViewController Extension

I converted the above answers into a UIViewController extension to tidy it away.

**Swift 3**

```
extension UIViewController {
    func setUpCustomTitleView(kerning: CGFloat) {

        let titleLabel = UILabel()

        guard let customFont = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-SemiBold", size: 18) else { return }

        let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.gray,
                      NSFontAttributeName: customFont,
                      NSKernAttributeName: kerning] as [String : Any]

        guard let title = title else { return }

        let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: attributes)

        titleLabel.attributedText = attributedTitle
        titleLabel.sizeToFit()
        navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
    }
}
```

Call the extension function from the viewDidLoad() of your view controller.

```
setUpCustomTitleView(kerning: 2.0)
```