# How to get voice over to read out title when new view controller is pushed?

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

In the setting app if I double tap on the 'General' row.  It pushes the the general view controller.  It then says

> "General"

(The name of the current view controller)

Then

> "Settings, back button"

(The name of the selected item)

However in my app with a custom `self.navigaitonItem.titleView` it only says

> "Home, Back Button"

How do I get it to read out the name of the screen? (I tired to set `self.title`)

Answer (score 1):

I havent tested it but you might need to check out the accessibilityLabel property of the view. 
From documentation:

> By default, standard UIKit controls and views have labels that derive from their titles. If you provide a custom control or view, however, you need to set this property appropriately so that assistive applications can supply accurate information to users with disabilities.

Comment: This is a good point but the `titleView` is a plain `UILabel` so the `accessibilityLabel` is set automatically.  If I tap on the title view it reads it out correctly.  I am starting to think this is a iOS bug but I can't find a good workaround.

Comment: Maybe the title is set after the push? try init methods to set the title.

Comment: Nope - didnt work.. I think that the title is read when the view appears on the screen.

Comment: You also need to set a trait of UIAccessibilityTraitHeader on the custom title view. Use a bitwise-or to add it to the default traits of the UILabel.