# How to control what the default selected voice over element is when a new view is presented?

Tags: ios, accessibility

When a new view controller is presented, the default selected element by voice over seems to be the first element on the page which is normally the back button.

How do you change this behaviour so that a different element is selected by default?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to change the default behaviour? It would need to provide a real usability advantage to non-sighted users to make it worth their time to learn your new non-standard navigation.

Comment: @stringy - You may be right, but I was thinking about custom views also if I could solve this issue manually... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990907/how-to-get-voice-over-to-read-out-title-when-new-view-controller-is-pushed

Answer (score 1):

You can define the first selected element by using the [UIAccessibilityPostNotification](http://a11y.forge.orange-labs.fr/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#notify-a-content-change) method in the `viewDidAppear` of your new view controller for instance.

Provide your accessible element as the incoming parameter of this function and it should work.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification,
                                    yourFirstDisplayedAccessibleElement)
}
```

I suggest to use `UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification` because the hint of the new focused element is read out by VoiceOver unlike  `UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification` *(don't know why ???)*.